# How to read protocol messages exchanged in local Java software?

Tags: java, protocols

I wrote a game that has client-server architecture. A server first runs at port 12345. Two clients connect to port 12345 and they start exchanging messages.

I want to see what client sends to server and vice versa for testing purposes, without depending on my software. How can I see them?

Using Java on Ubuntu 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a network sniffer, for example on of these two:

- tcpdump http://www.rationallyparanoid.com/articles/tcpdump.html
- Wireshark https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DBZiKpbHO0

Comment: Thanks! Wireshark doesn't let me check things like "/r/n" because it messes up the messages (it converts machine code to messy looking output). Anything can be done about that?

Comment: @mmswe not sure I understand the problem. You have binary view in wireshark, where you can see all your captured messages as a set of hex values, - so you can check them 'as is' without any conversion.

Comment: @mmswe by the way, you can also capture all the traffic and save it to a binary file by using 'tcpdump -w' option - and then you can investigate the traffic by a HEX-viewer (or even load it into wireshark for further investigation).

Answer (score 2):

You can use sniffers like Wireshark.

Comment: @perror Certainly it provides an answer. What on earth are you talking about?